# Direct an Azure Function App to accept only Application/json

Tags: azure, azure-functions, postman, azure-function-app, azure-functions-runtime

**Direct an Azure Function App to accept only Application/json**

Hi, I'm using an Azure Function and testing it through Postman.

My requirement is when we pass **Content-Type** other than **"application/json"**, I'm expecting my Azure Function to return saying **"Invalid Content - Type".**

The above need I'm able to achieve with the Code changes as below.

**if(HTTPRequest.Headers["Content-Type"] != "application/json")** -- then returing "Invalid Content - Type"

But is it possible and is there any way we can achieve the same using Configuration Setting (i.e host.json) in Azure Function App ?

Also, I have tried adding the below under customHeaders in host.json file. But it didn't work.

"Accept": "application/json"

"Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "application/json"

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: For V1 function, we set webHookType as genericJson in function.json,see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#configuration

Comment: Hi Stanley, Thanks for your reply. As per the documentation, webHookType is applicable to V1 function. (i.e Supported only for the version 1.x runtime). In our case, we are using Version 2.x So I'm still exploring available options to achieve this need.

Answer (score 0):

> But is it possible and is there any way we can achieve the same using
> Configuration Setting (i.e host.json) in Azure Function App ?

No, azure function v2 host.json doesn't have this setting.

And [Webhooktype attribute has been removed](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/commit/d7c8d3155947f642eacd9d493dc8a99d52622754). Now it is not supported in azure function v2: